# I am facing an error in react-native android mobile app. App is working fine on latest phones and latest android OS but it is crashing on older phones

Tags: android, react-native

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my application. It runs smoothly during development, but when I deploy it to production, it starts throwing errors. I've been able to access crash details through the Google Play Console, and the error message displayed there is as follows: 
{com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException }

The complete Stack trace you can see in the 1ST screenshot and you can see the effected android devices & OS in the 2ND screenshot.

[image]

[image]